# New to SQL - How to compare data from two sets of joined tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to compare a set of multiple tables against another set of multiple tables in a SQL database. Admittedly, I'm very novice to SQL so please forgive me if my terminology is incorrect.

I have 6 individual tables in my database. 3 of those are comprised of current month's data and the other three are prior month's data.  I need to produce a report that shows current month data, but also compare the account balance against the prior month - I need to create a column that will list "true" or "false" based on whether the account balances match.

I have joined the three current month's data tables together and I have joined the three prior month's data tables together.

The two sets of tables are identical.  Below is a description of the tables - There is one set prefixed "CURRENT" and one prefixed "PRIOR":

```
BALANCE:
    EntityID
    AccountID
    AccountBalance

ENTITY:
    ID
    Label
    Description

ACCOUNT:
    ID
    AccountNumber
    Description
```

The report I need to provide should list the following from the current month's data:

```
Label     
Description 
AccountNumber   
AccountDescription  
AccountBalance
```

I need to add a column called "**Changed**" at the end of the report.  This column should have a "True" or "False" value depending on whether or not the current & prior account balances match.

Thus far, I have only been able to join the tables.  I'm unsure how to edit this query to compare the current month dbo.CURRENT_BALANCE.AccountBalance against the prior month's dbo.PRIOR_BALANCE.AccountBalance

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    dbo.CURRENT_ENTITY.Label, 
    dbo.CURRENT_ENTITY.Description AS Entity, 
    dbo.CURRENT_ACCOUNT.AccountNumber, 
    dbo.CURRENT_ACCOUNT.Description AS AccountDescription, 
    dbo.CURRENT_BALANCE.GLAccountBalance
FROM     
    dbo.CURRENT_BALANCE 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CURRENT_ENTITY ON dbo.CURRENT_BALANCE.EntityID = dbo.CURRENT_ENTITY.ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CURRENT_ACCOUNT ON dbo.CURRENT_BALANCE.AccountID = dbo.CURRENT_ACCOUNT.ID 
    CROSS JOIN dbo.PRIOR_BALANCE 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PRIOR_ENTITY ON dbo.PRIOR_BALANCE.EntityID = dbo.PRIOR_ENTITY.ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PRIOR_ACCOUNT ON dbo.PRIOR_BALANCE.AccountID = dbo.PRIOR_ACCOUNT.ID
```

The query above returns my expected results:

```
Label   Entity                      AccountNumber   AccountDescription  AccountBalance
21      Company ABC                 1               Customer Sales      25
21      Company ABC                 2               Customer Sales      568
22      XYZ Solutions               3               Vendor Sales        344
23      Number 1 Products           4               Vendor Sales        565
24      Enterprise Inc              5               Wholesale           334
24      Enterprise Inc              6               Wholesale           5452
24      Enterprise Inc              7               Wholesale           5877
26      QWERTY Solutions            8               Customer Sales      456
27      Acme                        9               Customer Sales      752
28      United Product Solutions    10              Vendor Sales        87
```

What I would like to do is have a result similar to:

```
Label   Entity                      AccountNumber   AccountDescription  AccountBalance  Changed
21      Company ABC                 1               Customer Sales      25              FALSE
21      Company ABC                 2               Customer Sales      568             FALSE
22      XYZ Solutions               3               Vendor Sales        344             FALSE
23      Number 1 Products           4               Vendor Sales        565             FALSE
24      Enterprise Inc              5               Wholesale           334             TRUE
24      Enterprise Inc              6               Wholesale           5452            FALSE
24      Enterprise Inc              7               Wholesale           5877            TRUE
26      QWERTY Solutions            8               Customer Sales      456             FALSE
27      Acme                        9               Customer Sales      752             FALSE
28      United Product Solutions    10              Vendor Sales        87              FALSE
```

I have no idea where to go from here.  Would appreciate any advise from this group!

Comment: If you can reach the prior's account balance, then you can show FALSE/TRUE with a simple `CASE`.  The cross join seems odd, shouldn't it be by entity and account also?

Comment: You probably want an outer join, not a cross join, for this. I am not sure why entity id changes though, balance I can understand.

Comment: EzLo, thank you for the feedback. Still trying to wrap my head around joins.

Comment: Igor, thank you! I'm still trying to learn about joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work as a way to compare the 2 values.
I have added aliases to table names to help with reading;

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
     ce.Label
    ,ce.Description AS Entity
    ,ca.AccountNumber
    ,ca.Description AS AccountDescription
    ,cb.GLAccountBalance
    ,CASE
            WHEN cb.GLAccountBalance = p.PriorBalance THEN 'False'
            WHEN cb.GLAccountBalance <> p.PriorBalance THEN 'True'
        END AS [Changed]
    FROM dbo.CURRENT_BALANCE cb
    INNER JOIN dbo.CURRENT_ENTITY ce ON cb.EntityID = ce.ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CURRENT_ACCOUNT ca ON cb.AccountID = ca.ID 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                 pe.ID AS PE_ID
                ,pa.ID AS PA_ID
                ,pb.GLAccountBalance AS PriorBalance
                FROM dbo.PRIOR_BALANCE pb
                INNER JOIN dbo.PRIOR_ENTITY pe ON pb.EntityID = pe.ID 
                INNER JOIN dbo.PRIOR_ACCOUNT pa ON pb.AccountID = pa.ID 
            ) p ON p.PE_ID = ce.ID AND p.PA_ID = ca.ID
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you SO SO much!!  I must have spent 30+ hours trying different options and reading tutorials and never came close to an answer.  The aliases are very helpful as well!  And this will be a huge help personally going forward - now that I can see how this works with my own tables & data.  I can't thank you enough for taking the time to answer.

Comment: No problem at all, happy I could help. Everyone on stack overflow was a novice at one point. Just very good how detailed and well laid out your question was. At times new users can post vague questions that end up leading to people having to ask so many follow-on questions just to try understand what the original question was. you had sample data, sample query (shows you made an effort before asking the community) and clearly explained your issue and goal. The time that you put into your question helps other users to answer you quicker.